# Why can't I serialize/stringify this array of points?

Tags: javascript, json, svg, stringify

I just want to create a two-dimensional array of SVG points, and save it to a database.  I can't seem to stringify the array though.  Can anyone figure out why?  I feel I'm missing something obvious.  Thanks.

Here is the code:

```
var timelinedata = [
[]
];  // two dimensional array

timelinedata[1] = new Array();
timelinedata[1][2] = svg.createSVGPoint();  //svg object created elsewhere
timelinedata[1][2].x = 100;
timelinedata[1][2].y = 101;

console.log(timelinedata);
console.log(JSON.stringify(timelinedata));
```

Printing out the array shows the values stored as expected:

> [Array[0], Array[3]] 0: Array[0] 1: Array[3] 2: SVGPoint x: 100 y: 101

but the stringify returns an empty array:

> [[],[null,null,{}]]

What's going on?

Here is the fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/1xLgz7o1/

Comment: you set the 3rd slot in the sub-array instead of the 1st, thus a hole of 2 slots. `timelinedata[1][0] =`...

Comment: I thought the same thing, but even here... https://jsfiddle.net/tkq2u6yg/ it's the same issue @dandavis

Comment: `JSON.stringify` only works with own, enumerable properties. No inherited or non-enumerable properties will be included.

Comment: oh, and you can't JSON the native object returned by createSVGPoint(), only more-or-less "plain" objects can be turned to JSON off the bat